# App does not install on android device by an unknown failure

Tags: android, android-studio

I try installing my app for the first time on a Nexus 5.
The android studio then tells me I need to uninstall my app inorder to install it (The app never exsited on the phone) and then asks me to unistall the app, I agree and he tries to unistall but an error occurs:

> 

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-08a9df88021f8ec8
Uploading file
    local path: D:\USER\Desktop\Yoav\AndroidProject\Example\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.user.example
Installing com.example.user.example
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.user.example"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.user.example
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

At this part the studio asks me to uninstall after pressing ok:

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.user.example
>
> **Unknown failure**

I think it's because the app does not exsit on the phone, but if the app does not exsit why does it even want me to delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be because of the package name. Check weather is there any app with the same package name that you created before. com.example is not a good practice to use for you practice projects even.

I may be not right but from the information provided this is what I can say.

Comment: The cause was the name of my application, Thanks alot! (:

Comment: I had a similar problem, same app name with different package name, leads to the same error. I had a legacy app like that, uninstalling it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It happenes because the `.apk` you built and are trying to install is missing the `classes.dex` file. This can happen for various reasons but most of the time (for me) the build process gets stuck somehow.

Open Task Manager and kill all following processes:

```
cmd.exe
conhost.exe
find_java.exe
```

Then clean and build your project.

**Also make sure you use latest Build tools (now 21.1.1).**

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I finally had to reboot the device to solve it.